# Is there a need to consider the moment generated by horizontal water pressure in a pool?

Tags: structural-engineering, beam

Suppose there's a pool  which is supported by 4 beams (Perimeter beams)and 4 columns. When designing the beam should we consider the moment generated  due to the horizontal water pressure? (I'm using BS 8110 for designing)

Comment: Will the beams span the depth of the pool (will they be the pool's "walls")?

Comment: No, there's a separate RC wall of 1.5m on top of the beam. The beam is 450x225

Comment: The stiffness of what is between the water and the beams is important too.

Comment: I assume the beams will be supporting the pool's bottom slab, correct?

Comment: Can we have a sketch of the proposed design?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the design. The pool walls are going to resist the pressure and in return they are going to "bulge out" a bit. If there is enough clearance between the beams and the walls then the beams are only going to take any incidental side loading of the structure. That is if the column supports are designed correctly and do not induce any moments in the beams.

The devil is in the details, and there aren't much of them included in the question to effectively answer.

PS. Do you have access to any FEA software?

Answer (score 2):

Usually continuity is to be maintained between all joints - wall/slab/beam, and side wall/side wall, or sidewalls/column, to provide water tightness. So, yes, moments due to the pool water (horizontally and vertically) need to be considered.